# I was listening to music on my Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini when the sound coming from my headphones got really low.

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, audio, music, headphones

The Phone is three days old, and suddenly all music coming from my headphones (yes, tried different ones, and they work the same way, really low sound) got really low. The headphones work on all other devices, but the sound on my Samsung mini is really low. My Phone is not rooted. Pls help!

Answer (score 1):

Hold down the power button for 10 seconds it should reboot it this fixed my problem

Comment: I had the same problem, the sound in headphones suddenly went very low. It works with the reboot.
Thanks for the fix.